How to escape underscore whilte generating RTF file using Officer Package
I am generating rtf document using officer package. I have footnotes which contains path to the document and it has underscore in it. These unsderscores are missing when the rft is generated.
Example text in footnote: folder1/folder2/test_output.rtf
printed output in rtf file:  folder1/folder2/test output.rtf
How I can keep underscore in the text.
I tried to escape using "\_" but it is not working.

I found that underscore was not displayed because of line spacing between the lines. How can I reduce the spacing between line but keep it underscore displayed. When I generate docx file there is no linespacing issue.

I was able to fix the issue with the help of flextable::height() and flextable::hrule(rule = "exact")
